# How to stop appending when reaching user's specific page width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I stop the the appending of the `<div>`'s when it reaches the end of the user's page?  Do I have to build a fixed-width div as a container that can find the browser's default window setting?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var color_array = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
var randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)];

setInterval(function() {
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            $("#box").append("<div style='background-color:" + randColor + "; height:20px; width:20px; float:left;'></div>"); 
            randColor = color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)]; }
        }, .000001);
});
```

Comment: Going to need more info on this one in order to answer your question. Are you trying to create a single row of random colored squares to fill the width of `#box`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(box = document.getElementById('box')).style.display = 'table'; //Shrink-wrap
while (box.offsetWidth < innerWidth) {
    box.innerHTML += "<div style='background-color:" + color_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * color_array.length)] + "; height:20px; width:20px; float:left;'></div>"; //No need for a randColor var
}
box.style.display = ''; //Get rid of inline styles
```

Answer (score 0):

Semi-bad solution when #box div takes all remaining place. Example with another div near:

http://jsfiddle.net/naaj6/7/

```
$("#box").css({'height' : $(window).height() - $("#bigDiv").height() + 'px'});
if ($("#box").height() >= $(window).height() -40) clearInterval(crazyInterval);
```